# Functions throw app defined error when called from Excel Addin Module but work fine when used in the scope of the workbook

Tags: vba, excel, add-in

I have the following example:

```
Sub TestArray()
On Error GoTo errCatch

Dim resultArray(2, 2) As Variant
resultArray(0, 0) = "00"
resultArray(1, 0) = "10"
resultArray(2, 0) = "20"
resultArray(0, 1) = "01"
resultArray(1, 1) = "11"
resultArray(2, 1) = "21"
resultArray(0, 2) = "02"
resultArray(1, 2) = "12"
resultArray(2, 2) = "22"

Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A1").Resize(3, 3) 'row,col
myRange.Value = resultArray

errCatch:
   If Err Then
   MsgBox Err.Description
   End If
End Sub
```

When called from within the scope of the active workbook, for example a button on the worksheet, it works great.

When called as from a module in an addin (.xlam), I get the "Application-Defined or Object-defined" error thrown on this line:

```
Set myRange = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A1").Resize(3, 3) 'row,col
```

I see this same behavior when i work with functions/properties on range objects like .value= and .select.

The only thing i can think of is scope, but i can set other range properties just fine line border styles and colors.

Any help would be great...

Thank you in advance, Mark

Answer (score 0):

I would add some code to check whether the sheet "Sheet4" exists in the workbook where you want to run the add-in.

```
Sub TestArray()
'On Error GoTo errCatch

Dim resultArray(2, 2) As Variant
resultArray(0, 0) = "00"
resultArray(1, 0) = "10"
resultArray(2, 0) = "20"
resultArray(0, 1) = "01"
resultArray(1, 1) = "11"
resultArray(2, 1) = "21"
resultArray(0, 2) = "02"
resultArray(1, 2) = "12"
resultArray(2, 2) = "22"

' Testing if sheet exists
Dim wsTest As Worksheet
Const strSheetName As String = "Sheet4"
Set wsTest = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
Set wsTest = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(strSheetName)
On Error GoTo 0
If wsTest Is Nothing Then
    Worksheets.Add.Name = strSheetName
End If

Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A1").Resize(3, 3) 'row,col
myRange.Value = resultArray

errCatch:
   If Err Then
   MsgBox Err.Description
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I added the check code and this also fails. when debugging it finds that the sheet is missing and then executes your line "Worksheets.Add.Name = strSheetName" without error, but the sheet does not get created.

Comment: It works on my Ms Excel 2010 and 2013. Did you check File->Options->Trust Center->Trust Center Settings ->
Macro Settings ?

Comment: Another idea. Try  ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add.Name = strSheetName instead of  Worksheets.Add.Name = strSheetName

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is what I do to make it work.
1. create a xlam file. Alt+F11, new module, paste the code there:

```
Sub TestArray()
'On Error GoTo errCatch

Dim resultArray(2, 2) As Variant
resultArray(0, 0) = "00"
resultArray(1, 0) = "10"
resultArray(2, 0) = "20"
resultArray(0, 1) = "01"
resultArray(1, 1) = "11"
resultArray(2, 1) = "21"
resultArray(0, 2) = "02"
resultArray(1, 2) = "12"
resultArray(2, 2) = "22"

' Testing if sheet exists
Dim wsTest As Worksheet
Const strSheetName As String = "Sheet4"
Set wsTest = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
Set wsTest = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(strSheetName)
On Error GoTo 0
If wsTest Is Nothing Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add.Name = strSheetName
End If

Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A1").Resize(3, 3) 'row,col
myRange.Value = resultArray

errCatch:
   If Err Then
   MsgBox Err.Description
   End If
End Sub
```

2. save as xlam file.
3. Open a new file, mine is called Zeszyt2.xlm, add xlam as an add-in. My xlam file is called Zeszyt1.xlam
4. In Zeszyt2.xlm file go to the vba editor (Alt+F11), check the name of the add-in.
5. In Zeszyt2.xlm add a new module and write there:

   ```
   Sub something()
   Run "'Zeszyt1.xlam'!TestArray" `the name of the add-in file attached to xlm file
   End Sub
   ```
6. Save the xlm file.
7. In Excel go to Developer, click Macro button, choose "something", run the macro

On my computer it works without any errors.